# Linking router-link and scrollBehavior not working - Vue 3 and Ionic 6

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3, vue-router4

My navigation from a side menu to a specific link on the main page is not working with  `ion-router-link` and `scrollBehavior`

**router/index.js**

```
const routes = [
...
  {
    path: "/books",
    component: Books,
  },
  {
    path: "/books/:key",
    component: () => import("../views/BooksDetails.vue"),
  },  
];
...
 const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return { el: to.hash, left: 0, top: 64 };
    }
  },
```

**Link**  `` <router-link :to="`/books/${selectedBook}#${chapter.key}`"> Jump to chapter  </router-link> ``

**Target**
 `<div :id="chapter.key">`

Output of  `to`

```
  "fullPath": "/books/myBook1#chapter1",
  "hash": "#chapter1",
  "query": {},
  "path": "/books/myBook1",
  "params": { "key": "myBook1" },
  "matched": [
    {
      "path": "/books/:key",
      "meta": {},
      "props": { "default": false },
      "children": [],
      "instances": { "default": {} },
      "leaveGuards": {},
      "updateGuards": {},
      "enterCallbacks": {},
      "components": {
        "default": {
          "props": {},
          "__file": "BooksDetails.vue",
          "__hmrId": "42539a20"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {},
  "href": "/books/myBook1#chapter1"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67797577/1192011) from @[Masoud Ehteshami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8077228/masoud-ehteshami) to the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535838/scroll-behaviour-vuejs-not-working-properly).

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
  scrollBehavior(to, from, SavedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      const el = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
      if (el.length) {
        document.getElementById(el).scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      }
    } else if (SavedPosition) {
      return SavedPosition;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("app").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
  },
});
```